# I need to be able to give more spaces within a string in a view on the blade

Tags: html, css

I need to have more space between `TAM: {{$label->size}}` and `QUANT: {{$label->quantity}}` in the following code snippet:

```
<h4 class="mb-6">TAM: {{$label->size}} | QUANT: {{$label->quantity}}</h4>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `&nbsp;` is a code for space in HTML, you can used in laravel view

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the two bits of information in individual `<span>` tags and then use `style="margin-left:50px;` on the second span to move it away from the first one towards the right.

Since you are using a css framework you can also use a class instead of inline style to give the second span a margin-left.

```
<h4 class="mb-6">
    <span>TAM: {{$label->size}} |</span> 
    <span style="margin-left: 50px;">QUANT: {{$label->quantity}}</span>
</h4>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.